# How can I extract the value of velocity from h5 file for a given coordinates?

Tags: python, scipy

I am a new user in python. I have an `h5` file. I have imported the h5 file by using the following command:

```
f = h5py.File('filename', 'r')

list(f.keys())
dset = f[u'data']
dset.shape
dset[0:63,0:63,0:63]
```

and got the data looks like:

```
[ 8.06617710e-09, -4.54779939e-09, -8.05108869e-10],
[ 8.30818056e-09, -3.48755117e-09, -1.90735756e-09],
......
```

Now I have to find out the value of velocity for given coordinates in python. Can anyone help me how can I get the value of velocity for given coordinates by using `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is just a suggestion but consider using `with h5py.File("filename", "r") as f:` instead of what you have as it will close the file automatically for you. Also, please explain better how velocity should be calculated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I have found the h5 file by running a simulation. Actually, the h5 file contains the value of velocity. One can find out the value of velocity for any given coordinates (x, y, z) inside the box. For this purpose you have to call the interpolation function in python to find out the value of velocity at any points in the box. I am trying to find out the value by calling scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator but still can't find out the value.